# Is it possible to insert a string without using Console.WriteLine directly?

Tags: c#

for exemple:

```
    while (!incomingFiles.EndOfStream)
   {
        sLine = incomingFiles.ReadLine();
        sLine.Insert(iCharacterIndicator , "something");
        Console.WriteLine(sLine);
   }
```

I want to put a desired string at a specific spot using an indexOf pointing where I need to put my 
desired string, so i'm using the iCharacterIndicator to point out each new lines where I need to put my string, but the Insert wont show on my console except when I insert directly in a Console.WriteLine, thus, ruining my algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand the question at all: not what you are doing, not what you want. Can you please edit your question? Adding a [mcve] may also help.

Comment: A "specific spot" where? On the screen? Or do you just mean you're calling Insert, creating a new string, throwing the new string away without assigning it to a variable, and then writing `sLine`, which is unchanged? The [documentation for String.Insert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8) explains what it does. When you pass the *return value* from Insert() to Console.WriteLine(), it gets written to the console. When you do nothing with the return value from Insert(), it doesn't.

Comment: I also can't understand any aspect of what is being asked here.

Comment: @Amy He assumes strings are mutable. I assume. But it sure looks like it.

Answer (score 3):

Insert is not mutating sLine, it returns a new string, you should instead:

```
while (!incomingFiles.EndOfStream)
   {
        sLine = incomingFiles.ReadLine();
        sLine = sLine.Insert(iCharacterIndicator , "something");
        Console.WriteLine(sLine);
   }
```